# Recuperate value from Database using HQL

Tags: hql

Code productDaoImpl

```
    public List<Produit> parProduit(String cat){
    Query query = getEntityManger().createQuery( "from "+   getPersistentClass().getSimpleName()
            +" u where u.produit = :cat").setParameter( "cat", cat );
    List<Produit> module = (List) query.getResultList();

    return module;

}
```

produit value in database look like :

```
972-890-001;972-890-002;972-890-003;
```

View.html

```
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="messages" />
        <p:menubar>
            <f:facet name="options">
                <p:inputText id="pn" value="#{module.produit}"   required="true" placeholder="Search PN">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="11" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:menubar>
</h:form>
```

User should enter in input Text something like 972-890-001.
Result i never can get List; what should i do plz ??

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :

```
public List<Produit> parProduit(String cat){
    cat = "%" + cat + "%";
    Query query = getEntityManger().createQuery( "from "+ getPersistentClass().getSimpleName()
            +" u where u.produit LIKE :cat").setParameter( "cat", cat );
    List<Produit> module = (List) query.getResultList();
    return module;

}
```